# Getting value from inner array in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object in the following format

```
{
    "class": "model",
    "valueDataArray": [
        "category": "supply",
        "const": "123"
    },
    {
        "category": "prod",
        "text": "specify"
    }
],
"LinkArray": [
    {
        "from": 1,
        "to": 2
    },
    {
        "from": 2,
        "to": 3
    }
]
```

how can i get the values in valueDataArray? 
please Help

Comment: your JSON looks invalid.!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - it is indeed invalid

Comment: hint... http://jsonlint.com/ You're missing a '{' in your first item of `valueDataArray`.

Comment: Invalid Data array , check and repost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data.valueDataArray.category);
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using jquery then use

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(data.valueDataArray.category);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native JSON.parse() method. Also your JSON need to be fixed. Here is a working example (with JSON fixed)

http://jsbin.com/AqIYOcIY/1/edit